# Query over a collection of composite keys in RavenDB using C#

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have a collection in RavenDB of this class...

```
public class Report
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public int Quarter { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string ReportData { get; set; }
}
```

There is only one report per quarter, per year for each user (so the identifying key is `{ User, Quarter, Year }`.  I want to create a function to save a list of these Reports, overwriting old ones or inserting new ones as needed.  I came up with this:

```
public void Save(IList<Report> reports)
{
    session.Query<Report>()
        .Join(reports,
            x => new { x.User, x.Quarter, x.Year },
            y => new { y.User, y.Quarter, y.Year },
            (x, y) => new { OldReport = x, NewReport = y })
        .ForEach(report =>
        {
            if (report.OldReport != null)
                report.OldReport.InjectFrom(report.NewReport);
            else
                session.Store(report.NewReport);
        });

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, RavenDB does not support the `.Join` operator.  **Edit: I just realized that this also needs to be a right-outer-join for this to work, but I think it communicated my intent.**  I know I need to do some sort of Map Reduce to make this happen, but I'm new to RavenDB I can't find any good examples relevant to what I am doing.  Has anyone tried something like this?

P.S. The `.InjectFrom()` operation is using `Omu.ValueInjecter`, if anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but the *easiest* way would be to provide your own document key instead of using the one Raven generates.  This is often referred to as using "structured" or "semantic" keys.  [Here is a good description of the general technique](http://mattwarren.org/2012/07/12/fun-with-ravendb-documents-keys/).

Simply add a string `Id` property to your class.  You want the document key to reflect the unique key you described, so probably it should have a value such as `"reports/2013/Q1/bob"`  (but you might want a more unique value for `user`).

You can let .Net construct the key for you in the property getter, such as:

```
public class Report
{
    public string Id
    {
      get { return string.Format("reports/{0}/Q{1}/{2}", Year, Quarter, User); }
    }

    public string User { get; set; }
    public int Quarter { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string ReportData { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you store these documents, you simply store them:

```
foreach (var report in reports)
    session.Store(report);
```

If there is already a document with the same key, it will be overwritten with your new data.  Otherwise, a new document will be written.

If you can't manipulate the document key, other techniques you could look into are:

- You could run a query to delete any documents matching your changed data first.  Then you could insert all of the data.  But getting the query right will be difficult since there are multiple fields to match on.  It is possible, but the technique is challenging.
- You could use the [Patching API](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/partial-document-updates) to manipulate the data of the document already stored.  Although you would still have to query to figure out which are new inserts and which are updates.  Also, the patch would have to be tested against your entire database, so it would be slow.

I'm sure there are a few other ideas, but your safest and easiest bet is to go with semantic keys for the reports.